# FB app not showing up by insights

Tags: facebook-opengraph, facebook-insights, app-id

My App is not showing up when I access the FB insights page (at: https://www.facebook.com/insights/)
However, if I click the create app link on the left it will show up.
Additionally - it shows no insights & tells me that I need to publish an action at least one to submit the Open Graph code - which has been done numerous times already.
my app id is: 199931010133472

Comment: You should file a bug on Facebook, https://developers.facebook.com/bugs